# How to find last occurence index matching a certain value in a Pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I find the *last* occurrence index for a certain value in a Pandas Series?

For example, let's say I have a Series that looks like follows:

```
s = pd.Series([False, False, True, True, False, False])
```

And I want to find the last index for a `True` value (i.e. index 3), how would you go about it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`last_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index.html#pandas-dataframe-last-valid-index):

```
s = pd.Series([False, False, True, True, False, False])
s.where(s).last_valid_index()
```

Output:

```
3
```

Using @user3483203 example

```
s = pd.Series(['dog', 'cat', 'fish', 'cat', 'dog', 'horse'], index=[*'abcdef'])
s.where(s=='cat').last_valid_index()
```

Output

```
'd'
```

Comment: `s.where(s).last_valid_index()` :-)

Comment: IIUC, will this actually return the index, not just a numeric index?  So it would work even if you had a `datetimeindex` for example.  Very nice!

Comment: Well, the serie was just booleans, I was giving a more generic option.

Comment: This seems to be the most versatile and easy to read and worked as expected.

Answer (score 6):

Using `nonzero`

```
s.nonzero()[0][-1]
Out[66]: 3
```

Comment: FutureWarning: Series.nonzero() is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.Use Series.to_numpy().nonzero() instead

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.argmax` on your reversed Series if you are looking in a boolean array:

```
>>> len(s) - np.argmax(s[::-1].values) - 1
3
```

If you are looking for another value, just convert it to a boolean array using `==`

Here's an example looking for the last occurence of `dog`:

```
>>> s = pd.Series(['dog', 'cat', 'fish', 'cat', 'dog', 'horse'])
>>> len(s) - np.argmax(s[::-1].values=='dog') - 1
4
```

However, this will give you a numeric index.  If your series has a custom index it will not return that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generator expression with `next` and `enumerate`:

```
s = pd.Series([False, False, True, True, False, False])

res = len(s) - next(idx for idx, val in enumerate(s[::-1], 1) if val)  # 3
```

This will be more efficient for large series with a `True` value towards the end.